# git push heroku master Remote failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, heroku

[This is my error image getting on heroku logs --tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZhN5.png)

above is a given image of my errors. When I am trying to deploy my nodejs app Getting error on git push Heroku master .
.
.
.
Remote failed
working properly on local server. I am beginner please help my git id is cosmos-dx and there is a git repo of name Webdictionary

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the [nodemon docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), and taking the fact that you stated you are new, I think I know what is happening.

In the nodemon docs it gives you two ways to install, one is globally `npm install -g nodemon` and the other is to install it in the dev dependencies `npm install --save-dev nodemon`. Either of these options would make nodemon not be present if the build to heroku uses `npm install --only=production`. I assume they do that.

In your package.json file, change the `npm start` script to this:

```
"start": "node ser1.js"
```

As nodemon is not present in the heroku built application, your current start script will fail. If you want to continue using nodemon for local development you can add a new script:

```
"dev": "nodemon ser1.js"
```

From there to run your application, with nodemon, on your local machine you would run `npm run dev`

Comment: Now i left nodemon only doing Node then also i am getiing error

Comment: @AbhishekGupta is it the same error? can you update your question with the error message?